# HTTP POST with custom header from iphone to PHP script. How do you read the header?

Tags: php, iphone, http, header

This code works, and I can see the request go out to my php script through charles with my custom header GUID attached.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *loginRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:feedURLString]];
        NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[myRequestString UTF8String]length:[myRequestString length]];

    [ loginRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
    [ loginRequest setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];
    [ loginRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [ loginRequest setValue:@"testdatainguid" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GUID" ];
```

In php, I tried to read the header

```
    if(isset($_SERVER['GUID']))
{
    echo($_SERVER['GUID']);
}
```

I don't get any response. I tried getheaders, $_POST, $_GET and anything else I could think of, but I can't seem to get that data in my php. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd expect it in `$_SERVER['HTTP_GUID']`, as other HTTP headers are.

Comment: Basically I tried calling it "HTTP_GUID" inside the objective c code then looking for that inside the php, or I tried calling it GUID and looking for GUID, I didn't understand that the HTTP_ was added automatically. Thanks for your quick reply. Saved me a few hours. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can always print_r($_SERVER) to figure out if it's being set, and/or find out how it's being set.